# creating a pip package to allow others to to download - problems installing the created package

Tags: python, pip, pypi, python-packaging

I have created a package "honeywell_thermostat" and added it to github.  I want to add it to pypi by:
"python setup.py bdist_egg upload --quiet"

It looks like the package was installed correctly at pypi.python.org but it does not install correctly on any machine.

Here is my setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='honeywell_thermostat',
    packages=['honeywell_thermostat'],
    version='1.1.0',
    description='Python API for Honeywell thermostats',
    author='Jordan Thompson',
    author_email='Jordan@ThompCo.com',
    download_url='https://github.com/jorythompson/thermostat',
    url='https://github.com/jorythompson/thermostat',
    license='MIT',
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 3 - Alpha',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'Topic :: Software Development :: Build Tools',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.6',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7'
    ],
    keywords='develoment tools',
    install_requires=[],

)
```

my directory structure looks like this:

```
LICENCE.txt
README.md
setup.cfg
setup.py
[honeywell_thermostat]
  __init__.py
  logging.conf
  main.py
  thermostat.py
```

setup.cfg:

```
[metadata]
description-file = README.md
```

When I run the command on a machine with python version 2.7.12:

```
python setup.py bdist_egg upload --quiet
```

I get the following:

```
[jthompson@jrt thermostat]$ python setup.py bdist_egg upload --quiet
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing honeywell_thermostat.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to honeywell_thermostat.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to honeywell_thermostat.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'honeywell_thermostat.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'honeywell_thermostat.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\honeywell_thermostat
copying build\lib\honeywell_thermostat\main.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\honeywell_thermostat
copying build\lib\honeywell_thermostat\thermostat.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\honeywell_thermostat
copying build\lib\honeywell_thermostat\__init__.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\honeywell_thermostat
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\honeywell_thermostat\main.py to main.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\honeywell_thermostat\thermostat.py to thermostat.pyc
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\honeywell_thermostat\__init__.py to __init__.pyc
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying honeywell_thermostat.egg-info\PKG-INFO -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying honeywell_thermostat.egg-info\SOURCES.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying honeywell_thermostat.egg-info\dependency_links.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying honeywell_thermostat.egg-info\top_level.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
honeywell_thermostat.thermostat: module references __file__
honeywell_thermostat.thermostat: module MAY be using inspect.stack
creating 'dist\honeywell_thermostat-1.1.1-py2.7.egg' and adding 'build\bdist.win-amd64\egg' to it
removing 'build\bdist.win-amd64\egg' (and everything under it)
running upload
Submitting dist\honeywell_thermostat-1.1.1-py2.7.egg to https://pypi.python.org/pypi
Server response (200): OK
```

When I try to install the package on another machine (running python version 2.7.12):

```
pip install honeywell_thermostat
```

I get this:

```
Collecting honeywell_thermostat
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement honeywell_thermostat (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for honeywell_thermostat
```

Thanks in advance for any support or suggestions anyone may have

Comment: Just google this. There are many different things you can use. I would suggest PyInstaller, it's cross platform and (relatively) simple.

Comment: Don't add `.git` onto the end of your Github URLs. Read the Python Packaging documentation as well as the docs linked on PyPI, they explain exactly what each component in `setup.py` is for, as well as what to do when packaging a project for release. Hint: use https://testpypi.python.org to practice until you get it right.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestions.  I updated the git URLs, removing the .git at the end as you suggested.  I have been googling this problem for a couple of days and was able to get as far as I have by reading the docs and looking at examples, but from what I am seeing, it LOOKS like the package was installed correctly in pypi.python.org (when I look at the package and files on the website, it looks OK to me.  But my problem arises when I try to install the package.  Can someone please tell me where to look for the errors I am getting during the installation?

Comment: Here are the pieces I was missing (I will update my question and if you can mark this as a non-duplicate, I will mark it resoved):

python setup.py register -r pypi
python setup.py sdist upload -r pypi